# Stop system logging in Android Monitor when debugging on device

Tags: android, android-studio

When running app on device in `Android Monitor` there is planty of log lines like below. How can I stop do print these out?

```
07-20 19:05:10.574 5075-5082/com.j4nos.moviebuffs6 D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40006015, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
07-20 19:05:10.574 5075-5082/com.j4nos.moviebuffs6 D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
07-20 19:05:11.074 5075-5082/com.j4nos.moviebuffs6 D/jdwp: processIncoming
07-20 19:05:11.074 5075-5082/com.j4nos.moviebuffs6 D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x40006016, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
07-20 19:05:11.074 5075-5082/com.j4nos.moviebuffs6 D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34412604/239219) interesting things: Disable ADB Integration by unchecking in `Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration`.

Done like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9242148/239219). But then I can not start debugging on device. Any other idea?

Comment: it isn't "stop" so much as "filter", but have a look at Tom Mulcahy's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android)

Comment: Jesus, the only way to get rid of the shit is to do `grep` and `cut`?

Comment: Solution: Need to change filter level to `Warn` in `Android monitor`